# Solve the recurrence: T(n)=2T(n/2)+n/logn

Tags: time, complexity-theory, recurrence

I can find the sum of each row `(n/log n-i)` and also I can draw its recursive tree but I can't calculate sum of its rows.

```
T(n)=2T(n/2)+n/logn
```

`T(1) = 1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose n = 2^k;

We know for harmonic series (euler formula):

`Sum[i = 1 to n](1/i) ~= log(n) [n -> infinity]`

```
t(n) = 2t(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = 2(2t(n/4) + n/2/log(n/2)) + n/log(n)
     = 4t(n/4) + n/log(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = 4(2t(n/8) + n/4/log(n/4)) + n/log(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = 8t(n/8) + n/log(n/4) + n/log(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = 16t(n/16) + n/log(n/8) + n/log(n/4) + n/log(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = n * t(1) + n/log(2) + n/log(4) + ... + n/log(n/2) + n/log(n)
     = n(1 + Sum[i = 1 to log(n)](1/log(2^i)))
     = n(1 + Sum[i = 1 to log(n)](1/i))
     ~= n(1 + log(log(n)))
     = n + n*log(log(n)))
     ~= n*log(log(n)) [n -> infinity]
```

Answer (score 10):

When you start unrolling the recursion, you will get:

[image]

Your base case is `T(1) = 1`, so this means that `n = 2^k`. Substituting you will get:

[image]

The second sum behaves the same as [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and therefore can be approximated as `log(k)`. Now that `k = log(n)` the resulting answer is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking in such an old post, but I was looking to your answer and i've been trying to understand why the sum from i=0 to k-1 {1/(k-i)} behaves the same as harmonic series. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Ph. just write the sum as the actual summation of k-1 elements and it will be obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Follow Extended Masters Theorem Below.

Using Extended Masters Theorem `T(n)=2T(n/2)+n/logn` can be solved easily as follows.
Here `n/log n` part can be rewritten as `n * (logn)^-1`,
Effictively maaking value of p=-1.
Now Extended Masters Theorem can be applied easily, it will relate to case 2b of Extended Masters Theorem .

```
T(n)= O(nloglogn)
```

Follow this for more detailed explanation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aude2ZqQjUI